# PowerShell: How can I list the index of an item using format-table?

Tags: powershell, indexing

I wish to list the index of an item in a result table.

In this case I am using get-aduser with the filter option.

I am then using format-table with -Property to display only the properties I want.

I previously used a loop to display the items along with a counter to emulate the index but this was messy and I wanted it in a table.

Code:

```
$search_param = read-host "Enter search string: "
$search_param = "*" + $search_param + "*" # Construct search param.
$search_result = Get-ADUser -Filter {Surname -like $search_param -or GivenName -like $search_param -or SamAccountName -like $search_param}


$search_result | format-table -Property GivenName,Surname,SamAccountName
```

How can I get format-table to display the item index/position without using some kind of loop? ie, is there some kind of 'hidden' index property that I can simply provide to format-table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `format-table` CmdLet `-Property` param can be a new calculated property see [Format-table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315255.aspx) help.

Here is an example with a computed index on Get-Process objects.

```
$index=0
Get-Process  | Format-Table -Property @{name="index";expression={$global:index;$global:index+=1}},name,handles
```

Comment: +1, one thing I didn't like is having to declare the index outside the command itself, I think I can contribute here avoiding to create $index :) expression={($global:index+=1)}}

Comment: Interestingly, I have to set $global:index to -2 for me to get the correct results... (Verified by doing $search_result[1] and the indicated item and printed item do not match) But it works!

Answer (score 4):

The `ForEach-Object` cmdlet can be used to create a calculated "index" property for the `Format-Table` cmdlet

For Example:

```
$search_result | ForEach-Object {$index=0} {$_; $index++} | Format-Table -Property @{ Label="index";Expression={$index}; Width=5 },GivenName,Surname,SamAccountName
```

Additional References:

[Adding Array Index Numbers to PowerShell Custom Objects](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/09/23/adding-array-index-numbers-to-powershell-custom-objects/)

[ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-5.1)

[Format-Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 0):

```
$procs = Get-Process 
#option 1
$procs | Select @{N='Index'; E={$procs.IndexOf($_)}}, name, handles

#option 2
$procs | Format-Table -Property @{name="index";expression={$procs.IndexOf($_)}},name,handles
```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion you can't, you need to extend the objects with an Index property and include it in your `Format-Table` command.

Comment: What about Format-table calculated property ?

Comment: You need to maintain a global counter and display it in each object, on the other hand, calculated property works on each item in the pipeline, how would you do that? It may be possible though...